# Writing a select statement that compares information within the same column without creating a seperate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have the following table:

```
 Age    Name    School
 22     x       ryerson
 31     y       york
 14     z       U of T
```

and I would like to write a query with the following result:

```
  Age  Name School(of the next-youngest person)     
  22    x    U  of T
  31    y    ryerson
  14    z    null
```

How would I write this query WITHOUT creating another function or passing a parameter to another function?  I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Oracle, mysql, SQL Server? They all behave a little different :)

Comment: You want to ascertain the oldest person younger than a given age... but you can't use the MAX function. That's unfortunate, since finding the MAX < [some age] seems like the obvious approach. Why the restriction?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, then it should have that tag.  What do you mean that you can't use the MAX function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT o.Age, o.Name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 c.School
    FROM Students c
    WHERE c.Age < o.Age
    ORDER BY c.Age DESC) as school
FROM Students o
```

Comment: Your subquery is missing an `ORDER BY c.Age DESC`

Answer (score 3):

No idea why can't you use `MAX`. Anyway, this should do:

```
SELECT A.Age, A.Name, B.School
FROM YourTable A
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT TOP 1 School
                FROM YourTable
                WHERE Age < A.Age
                ORDER BY Age DESC) B
```